# How to use SqlRetryLogicBaseProvider to retry connections during Azure SQL scaling up/down

Tags: c#, .net, azure-sql-database, retry-logic, resiliency

I have an Azure SQL database, that has automatic schedules to scale up/down depending on dtu usage. During the scale up/down all connections are  dropped. So I need to apply a retry logic in my application, so the application will try to execute again when the database finishing scaling up/down.

I am using C# .NET framework 4.7, with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` library that has an `SqlRetryLogicBaseProvider` to configure.

After configuring the provider, and calling `ExecuteReader`, I scale up the database, and the connection is lost, but the retry logic is never triggered, and the query just returns this error:

> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
> A severe error occurred on the current command.
> The results, if any, should be discarded.

This error number is added to my error list.

Here is my code:

```cs
internal class Program
{
        private const string CnnStringFormat = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = dbtest; User ID = sa; Password=aaaaaa;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True";
        private static SqlConnection s_generalConnection = new SqlConnection(CnnStringFormat);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("spGetLoadTest") { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure };
            
            var options = new SqlRetryLogicOption()
            {
                NumberOfTries = 5,
                MaxTimeInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                DeltaTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                TransientErrors = new List<int> { -1, -2, 0, 109, 233, 997, 1222, 10060, -2146232060, 596 }
        };

            var provider = SqlConfigurableRetryFactory.CreateExponentialRetryProvider(options);
            
            provider.Retrying += (object s, SqlRetryingEventArgs e) =>
            {
                NotificaRetry(e);
                var cmd = s as SqlCommand;
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 3000;
            };

            s_generalConnection.RetryLogicProvider = provider;
            s_generalConnection.Open();

            comando.Connection = s_generalConnection;
            comando.RetryLogicProvider = provider;

            SqlDataReader leitor = null;
            try
            {
                comando.CommandTimeout = 300;
                leitor = comando.ExecuteReader();
                var count = leitor.Depth;
                var colunas = leitor.FieldCount;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void NotificaRetry(SqlRetryingEventArgs e)
        {
            int attempts = e.RetryCount + 1;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine($"attempt {attempts} - current delay time:{e.Delay} \n");
            Console.WriteLine($"error: {e.Exceptions[e.RetryCount-1].Message} \n");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        }
}
```

I expected that during the scale up, as the line `comando.ExecuteReader()` is executing, the application would try again, and not return an error.

**Edited**

What I realised after a lot of testing is that when I get an error number 0, retry logic is never triggered, even if it is on the error list. Sometimes I got an error 109, and with error 109, retry logic is triggered. This is getting a lot of confusing to me, are there some types of error that will never trigger even if they are listed to retry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to deal with database connectivity issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570306/proper-way-to-deal-with-database-connectivity-issue)

Comment: after reading all the answers and links, I still can not make it work right. I am already implemeting a retry logic, using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient RetryLogicProvider, the logic works fine if it trys to connect and the database is offline, but when the database gets offline during comand.ExecuteReader() call, command returns an error and retry logic is never trigged, i need it to be triggerd in this kind of situation, so the application can run again.

Comment: This seems to describe your issue: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1454

Comment: I am not specifying CommandBehavior.CloseConnection, i am using ExecuteReader() with no parameters, wich does not use CommandBehavior.CloseConnection.

I edited my post, describing the results after some tests. When error number is 0, retry logic is never triggered, even if it 0 is at error list of SqlRetryLogicConfiguration. When error number 109 occurs, retry logic is triggered. Is there some impossibility to retry with erro number 0? Unfurtanaly this is the error i receive most of the time I scale up/down my azure sql database